# Angular 'Unknown provider error' (of a factory file) when I use ngroute

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, factory, angular-providers

I want to pick this html page:

```html
<h2 class="sub-header" style="color:#4e67c3;">Elenco dipendenti</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="thetable">
                
             
                <tr> 
                    <th class="th2">Nome</th>  
                    <th class="th2">Cognome</th>  
                    <th class="th2">Data di Nascita</th>   
                    <th class="th2">Telefono</th>  
                    <th class="th2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Sesso&nbsp;&nbsp;</th> 
                    <th class="th2">&nbsp;StaffId&nbsp;</th>
                    <th class="th2">Email</th> 
             </tr> 
             
              
              <tr ng-repeat="staff in staffs">  
                 
           <td> {{ a }}</td> 
            <td> {{ staff.name }}</td>  
            <td> {{ staff.surname }}</td>    
            <td> {{ staff.birthDate }}</td>
            <td> {{ staff.phone }}</td> 
            
   
            <td>
                <div ng-switch on="staff.gender">
                <span ng-switch-when="true">Uomo</span>
                <span ng-switch-when="false">Donna</span>
                </div>
            </td>
                    
            
            <td> {{ staff.idstaff }}</td>  
            <td> {{ staff.staffLogin.email }}</td> 
    

            </tr>  
          
            </table>

      <script src="./scripts/bootstrap.min.js.download"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/docs.min.js.download"></script>
               
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script> 
 <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.js"></script> -->

             
      <script src="scripts/rest-services.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
  <!--  <script src="scripts/emailchecker.js"></script>  --> 
    <script src="scripts/angular-bootstrap-datepicker.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <!-- <script src="scripts/number-directive.js"></script> -->
    <script type="application/javascript"></script>
```

In this page, when I click one button:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0069)https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/ -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/puzzle.png" />
      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/angular-bootstrap-datepicker.css" /> --> <!-- penso di poterlo togliere -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/mainBoot.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/scrollbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/noscroll_numberfield.css">
    
 
 

  <!--  <script src="scripts/emailchecker.js"></script>  --> 
 
 <!--   <script src="scripts/angular-bootstrap-datepicker.js" charset="utf-8"></script> -->
   <!-- <script src="scripts/number-directive.js"></script> -->
    <script type="application/javascript"></script>
    
    <title>Pannello Amministratore</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="./styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="./styles/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <style id="holderjs-style" type="text/css"></style></head>

  <body ng-app="StaffManagement" background="images/sfondoblu3.png">

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand">FDDispenser</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="fixed_admin.html#/">Pannello Amministratore</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/#">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
           <li class="active"><a  href="#/showemp">Mostra Dipendenti</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/#">Mostra Catalogo</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/#">Mostra Macchinette</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/#">Mostra Acquisti</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="edit_employee.html">Aggiungi/Modifica Dipendente</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Crea/Modifica Catalogo</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Aggiungi/Modifica Famiglia</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Aggiungi/Modifica Categoria</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Aggiungi/Modifica Produttore</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Aggiungi/Modifica Ingrediente</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Aggiungi/Modifica Fabbrica di produzione</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Aggiungi/Modifica Macchinetta</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Aggiungi/Modifica Tipologia Macchinetta</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Aggiungi/Modifica Accessori</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Assegna Macchinetta a Dipendente</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Posiziona Macchinetta sul Territorio</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/dashboard/">Assegna Prodotti a Macchinetta</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
            
          <div ng-view></div>
            
            
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <!--  <script src="./Dashboard Template for Bootstrap_files/jquery.min.js.download"></script> -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script> 
 <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.js"></script> -->

      

    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main-admin.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      
    <script src="./scripts/bootstrap.min.js.download"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/docs.min.js.download"></script>
        

</body></html>
```

the ngroute function is in this js file called "main-admin.js":

```js
var app = angular.module("StaffManagement", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "home_admin.html"
    })
    .when("/showemp", {
        templateUrl : "provaEmp.html",
        controller: "StaffController"
    })
    .when("/paris", {
        templateUrl : "paris.htm"
    });
});


app.controller("StaffController", function($scope, $filter, $http, restService) {  
                

                
    $scope.name = "ciao";
    restService.allstaffworking(_getstaff, _error);
     function _getstaff(response){
                    if (response.data == ""){
                        console.log("Accesso non autorizzato")
                    }
                    $scope.staffs = response.data;  
                }
           
                function _success(response) {  
                   // console.log(staff.name);
                    console.log("successo");
                    
                    _refreshStaffData();  
                    _clearFormData();
                    _showSB();
                    console.log("cleared");
                
                }  
           
             
      });
```

When I click on the button "Mostra Dipendenti", from main-admin.js the application show me "provaEmpl.html":

```html
<h2 class="sub-header" style="color:#4e67c3;">Elensco dipendenti</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="thetable">
                
             
                <tr> 
                    <th class="th2">Nome</th>  
                    <th class="th2">Cognome</th>  
              
                    <th class="th2">Telefono</th>  
                    <th class="th2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Sesso&nbsp;&nbsp;</th> 
                    <th class="th2">&nbsp;StaffId&nbsp;</th>
                    <th class="th2">Email</th> 
             </tr> 
             
              
                
                 

            <td> {{ name }}</td>  
            <td> {{ name }}</td>    
            
            <td> {{ name  }}</td> 
            
   

                   <td> {{ name  }}</td>  
            
            <td> {{ name  }}</td>  
            <td> {{ name  }}</td> 
    

            
          
            </table>

    
      <script src="./scripts/bootstrap.min.js.download"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/docs.min.js.download"></script>
               
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script> 
 <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.js"></script> -->

 <script src="scripts/prova2.js"></script>
      <script src="scripts/rest-services.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
  <!--  <script src="scripts/emailchecker.js"></script>  --> 
    <script src="scripts/angular-bootstrap-datepicker.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <!-- <script src="scripts/number-directive.js"></script> -->
    <script type="application/javascript"></script>
```

using the controller "StaffController". But "StaffController" use some functions of another js file, a factory file, called rest-services.js:

```js
var app = angular.module("StaffManagement");  
app.factory("restService", function($http, $window) {  
    var REST_URL = "http://localhost:8080/FoodDrinkDispener/rest/";
    var minutes = 20; // Reset when storage is more than 20 minutes
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var setupTime = localStorage.getItem('setupTime');
    
    function _GetToken() {
        var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        if (token !== null) 
            return JSON.parse(token);
        else
        console.log("Non c'è un token");
    }
    
    
    function _SetToken(CurrentToken) { //uso localStorage al posto si sessionStorage
        localStorage.setItem("token", (CurrentToken === null) ? null : JSON.stringify(CurrentToken));
    }
    
    function _deleteToken(idtoken, _success, _error) {  
       return $http({  
            method : 'DELETE',  
            url : REST_URL+'tokenstaff/'+idtoken,  
            headers : {  
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'  
            }  
            }).then( _success, _error );  
        }
    
    function _RestSuccess(response) { //uso localStorage al posto si sessionStorage
        console.log("success"+response.status);
    }
    
    function _RestError(response) { //uso localStorage al posto si sessionStorage
        console.log("error"+response.status);
        if (response.status==404)
            $window.location.href="error404.html";
        else if(response.status==500)
            $window.location.href="error500.html";
            
    }
    
    function _DeleteByidLogin(loginform, _logsuccess, _logerror){
        return $http({  
                        method : 'GET',  
                        url : REST_URL+'stafflogin/'+loginform.email
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        _deleteToken(response.data, _logsuccess, _logerror);
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {  
                        console.log("ERRORE");
                        console.log(response.statusText);  
                    }); 
        }
    
    function _timerTokenControl(currentToken, _error){
        if(now-setupTime > minutes*60*1000) {
                if(currentToken!=null){
                    _deleteToken(currentToken.idtokenStaff, _error);
                }
                localStorage.clear();
                $window.location.href="login.html#/sessionExpired";
            }
    }
    


    
    return {
        login: function(loginform, _logsuccess, _logerror){
        _DeleteByidLogin(loginform, _logsuccess, _logerror);
            return $http({  
                method : 'POST',  
                url : REST_URL+'tokenstaff',
                data : angular.toJson(loginform), 
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {  
                    if (typeof response.data === 'object'){
                        var CurrentToken = response.data;
                        _SetToken(CurrentToken);
                        localStorage.setItem('setupTime', now)
                        
                        _logsuccess(response)
                        console.log("login andato a buon fine");
                        $window.location.href="fixed_admin.html";
                        return response.status;
                     }
                    else {
                        _SetToken(null);
                        _logerror(response);
                    }
                },function (response) {
                    _SetToken(null);
                    _logerror(response);
                }
                );
        },
        
        
        
             
        insertstaff: function(stafform, _giveLast, _error){
            var currentToken = _GetToken();

          /*  if(currentToken!=null){
                var Headers = {
                    token: currentToken.tokenStaff,
                };
            }*/
                
            _timerTokenControl(currentToken, _error);
            
            if (setupTime == null) {
                console.log("token scaduto");
                $window.location.href="login.html";
            }
            

            if (currentToken !== null) {
                return $http({  
                    method : 'POST',  
                    url : REST_URL+'staff',  
                    data : angular.toJson(stafform),  
                    headers : {  
                      token: currentToken.tokenStaff,
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'  
                    }  
                }).then( _giveLast, _error );
            }  else {
                    $window.location.href="login.html";
                    console.log("NON SEI LOGGATO!!!");
            }
        } ,
        
        
        /*
        insertstaff: function(stafform, _giveLast, _error){
            return $http({  
                method : 'POST',  
                url : REST_URL+'staff',  
                data : angular.toJson(stafform),  
                headers : {  
                            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'  
                }  
            }).then( _giveLast, _error );
            } ,
        */
        insertstafflogin: function(staffloginform, _giveLast, _error){
            var currentToken = _GetToken();

         /*   if(currentToken!=null){
                var Headers = {
                    token: currentToken.tokenStaff,
                };
            }*/
                
            _timerTokenControl(currentToken, _error);
            
            if (setupTime == null) {
                console.log("token scaduto");
                $window.location.href="login.html";
            }
            

            if (currentToken !== null) {
                return $http({  
                    method : 'POST',  
                    url : REST_URL+'stafflogin',  
                    data : angular.toJson(staffloginform),  
                    headers : {  
                        token: currentToken.tokenStaff,
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'  
                    }  
                }).then( _giveLast, _error ); //se errore allora DELETE staff, altrimenti sta stessa stafflogin
            }  else {
                    $window.location.href="login.html";
                    console.log("NON SEI LOGGATO!!!");
            }
            } ,
        
       
        
        allstaffworking: function(_getstaff, _error){
            var currentToken = _GetToken();

            if(currentToken!=null){
                var Headers = {
                    token: currentToken.tokenStaff,
                };
            }
                
            _timerTokenControl(currentToken, _error);
            
            if (setupTime == null) {
                console.log("token scaduto");
                $window.location.href="login.html";
            }
            

            if (currentToken !== null) {
            $http({  
                        method : 'GET',  
                        headers: Headers,
                        url : REST_URL+'staff/working'
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {  
                        _getstaff(response)
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {  
                        console.log(response.statusText);  
                    });  
               }  else {
                    $window.location.href="login.html";
                    console.log("NON SEI LOGGATO!!!");
            }
        },
        
        laststaff: function(_postStaffLogin, _error){
            var currentToken = _GetToken();

            if(currentToken!=null){
                var Headers = {
                    token: currentToken.tokenStaff,
                };
            }
                
            _timerTokenControl(currentToken, _error);
            
            if (setupTime == null) {
                console.log("token scaduto");
                $window.location.href="login.html";
            }
            

            if (currentToken !== null) {
                return  $http({  
                    method : 'GET',
                    headers: Headers,
                    url : REST_URL+'staff/getlast'  
                                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                                _postStaffLogin(response)
                                console.log(response);
                                return response.status; 
                                 //    console.log($scope.staffLast.idstaff);
                                 //   _postStaffLogin();
                            }, function errorCallback(response) {  
                                console.log(response.statusText);  
                            }); 
                }  else {
                    $window.location.href="login.html";
                    console.log("NON SEI LOGGATO!!!");
            }
        
    },
        
        deletestaff: function(stafform, _success, _error){
             var currentToken = _GetToken();

            if(currentToken!=null){
                var Headers = {
                    token: currentToken.tokenStaff,
                };
            }
                
            _timerTokenControl(currentToken, _error);
            
            if (setupTime == null) {
                console.log("token scaduto");
                $window.location.href="login.html";
            }
            

            if (currentToken !== null) {
                return $http({  
                    method : 'PUT',  
                    url : REST_URL+'staff',
                    data : angular.toJson(stafform),  
                    headers : {  
                        token: currentToken.tokenStaff,
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'  
                    }
                    }).then( _success, _error ); 
            }  else {
                    $window.location.href="login.html";
                    console.log("NON SEI LOGGATO!!!");
            }

            }
        
    }
    
    
});
```

The problem is this "restService" factory! It causes me this error:

```html
angular.js:12520 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: restServiceProvider <- restService <- StaffController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=restServiceProvider%20%3C-%20restService%20%3C-%20StaffController
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:68:12
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:4334:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:4482:39)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:4339:45
    at getService (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:4482:39)
    at invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:4514:13)
    at Object.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:4531:27)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:9197:28
    at link (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js:7:268)
    at invokeLinkFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js:8841:9) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

[image: Error message]

In fact, if I remove "restService" dependency and all the functions of rest-services.js from main-admin.js, it works..but I need to use some functions of restService factory from rest-services.js. How I can do?

Comment: can you make a working plnkr?

Comment: ok, just a moment

Comment: Your post looks like a big code dump. Did you just insert `rest-service.js` before `angular.js` in HTML? I suspect how can that work?

Comment: @Aravind this is my first plnkr...I'm not sure that it works.. https://plnkr.co/edit/IGky4BS8bV7RFiZM7QHP?p=preview

Comment: @31piy I have just try...but whitout ngroute it works fine. If u wants I post my code without ngroute

Comment: @AlfonsoSilvestri, add the files one at a time and ensure that the output is displayed on the right side of the screen.

Comment: @Aravind can I import my project without create new file manually?

Comment: no I haven't, but I can install it right away

Comment: done. I've sent a request to you

Comment: @AlfonsoSilvestri did you try including `<script src="scripts/rest-services.js"></script>` after line `<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>`

Comment: @appdroid I have just tryed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved import this script in in fixed_admin.html:

```js
<script src="scripts/rest-services.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try not to use var app = angular.module("StaffManagement")
just angular.module("StaffManagement").factory("restService", .....

you are redefining var app

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module("StaffManagement");
```

this means the `app` called `StaffManagement` is already created somewhere and you are just accessing it. But, actually you want to create this. For that, you need to be used as below.

```
var app = angular.module("StaffManagement", []);
```

Try to include files in this order(first to last)

`jquery`,
`angular`,
`your js files`